# PostgreSQL : Update multiple inner jsonb objects fields with same name

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, crud, jsonb

I have a table named `test` which has 2 columns : `(id int, md jsonb)`. `md` column can contain data like this

```
{
  "a": {
    ...
    "author": "alice"
    ...
  },
  "b": {
    ...
    "author": "alice"
    ...
  }
}
```

now I want to update all instances of `alice` to `bob`.

I got the ids of rows containing `alice` by doing

`select id from test, lateral jsonb_each(md) where md->>'author' = 'alice';`

Are there any Postgres facilities to update every inner object which contains the `author` field?

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: `jsonb_set()`? - but it would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model

Comment: how to use that to loop through every inner object of a jsonb and update values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name that it's better to review your storage. But it's interesting to do as an execrcise. I think the only way to do this is by expanding json with [`jsonb_each`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html), updating data with [`jsonb_set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html) and then aggregating it back with [`jsonb_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-aggregate.html):

```
update test as t set
    md = (
    select
        jsonb_object_agg(
            d.key,
            case
                when d.value->>'author' = 'alice' then
                    jsonb_set(d.value, '{author}', '"bob"')
                else
                    d.value
            end
        )
     from lateral jsonb_each(t.md) as d
    )
where
    exists (select * from jsonb_each(t.md) as d where d.value->>'author' = 'alice')
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2066e66e174025b5a61aaac8dfd126cb)